# Action parameter object property causes ArgumentNullException when nullable struct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

As I was accepting an object into one of my actions today I found that if my object had a property that was a nullable struct and I populated it I got an ArgumentNullException.

This is what it looked like (in extreme simplification, using GET to create a simpler example):

```
//Action
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Test(SuperClass model)
{
    return Json("The will not work...", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

//...

public class SuperClass
{
    public string ArbitraryProperty { get; set; }

    public SpecialDate SpecialDateA { get; set; }

    //This seems to be the problem
    public SpecialDate? SpecialDateB { get; set; }
}

public struct SpecialDate
{
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I called the following URL:
http://EXAMPLE.COM/Home/Test/?ArbitraryProperty=Foo&SpecialDateA.Year=2014&SpecialDateA.Month=8&SpecialDateA.Day=12&SpecialDateB.Year=2015&SpecialDateB.Month=9&SpecialDateB.Day=10
then I have set all the data I really need but I get an ArgumentNullException in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext construct.

The following URL would work however: http://EXAMPLE.COM/Home/Test/?ArbitraryProperty=Foo&SpecialDateA.Year=2014&SpecialDateA.Month=8&SpecialDateA.Day=12

So setting the nullable struct property as an action parameter in MVC5 doesn't work. In this case I'll just switch the struct for a class but it would be interesting for future use to know why this doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the ArgumentNullException is thrown by the MVC framework when deserializing the object in my request (see example URLS).
The Test action in the above code is placed in my HomeController in this example and the execution never gets as far as to enter the method, the error is thrown before that (when calling the example URL).

**EDIT 2:**
In regard of the comment by @Shoe I also tested the following URL:
http://EXAMPLE.COM/Home/Test/?ArbitraryProperty=Foo&SpecialDateA.Year=2014&SpecialDateA.Month=8&SpecialDateA.Day=12&SpecialDateB.Value.Year=2015&SpecialDateB.Value.Month=9&SpecialDateB.Value.Day=10

What I did was trying to assign SpecialDateB through its **Value** property but it doesn't seem to work either.

**Edit 3:**

To clarify **even further** here is an even easier example of the problem:

**This works:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Fest(int? foo)
{
    return Json("This will work", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Fest(Fee fee)
{
    return Json("This won't work...", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
...
public class Fee
{
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? Also, you may want to show some code that initializes this, or at least the method that throws the exception and the exception message.

Comment: The question is why the exception is thrown and the execution is the URL (although the URL is fake its structure is correct, it calls the Test action).

Comment: can you show the line, where you `deserialize` ?

Comment: The deserialization is run by the MVC framework when calling the service during the routing process, so I haven't written it. That's why I'm perplexed.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the line `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext` makes me think like if you might have some `dataannotation` attribute applied on some of the properties, and that is not being satisfied.
plus, why this way? when you can simply `post` the model data to action?

Comment: @Zeeshan: as I've written in my text the GET is to make a simpler example for this post. I'm really making a post call through ajax. I did, however, make a test MVC project and use the code above and make GET calls and I got the exact same error as with POST calls. The above code is what I used (the rest of the controller omitted) and I kept getting this error if I sent in data for SpecialDateB but not if I sent in null for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the way nullable structs work. `Value` is the only property on `SpecialDateB` (not Day, Month, Year) and it is immutable. I'm also thinking while your first struct won't generate an error, your properties will not get passed. Classes are definitely the way to go, since mutable structs are almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC's default model binder uses `Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)` to create your model and its properties and it has no special magic in place for handling `Nullable<>` types.

Since you're using a `Nullable<SpecialDate>` for "SpecialDateB", MVC gets a null reference when calling `Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)` as it has no initial value. MVC then updates the model state which triggers model validation.

This is where the crash comes in.

The `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext` ([MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.aspx)) used by MVC for its validation requires that the "instance" parameter (in this case the "SpecialDateB" property's value) is not null and throws an `ArgumentNullException` otherwise.

In short, MVC doesn't support the `Nullable<>` type for parameters (or parameters' properties, as in your case).

I'd recommend using a class instead of a struct until the MVC team has fixed support for `Nullable<>`.

**EDIT:**

To clarify my answer: What I meant by claiming that "MVC doesn't support the `Nullable<>` type for parameters" was for the presented case only. Simple types like `int`, `DateTime`, etc. works fine as nullable parameters. However, as soon as you create a complex type as a struct and attempts to use it as a nullable parameter, MVC fails to handle it. Regardless of whether you specify values for it, or whether it is optional. Sorry for not being clear in my above answer.

Comment: MVC does support Nullable types though. You can use `int?` or `Datetime?` as parameters.

Comment: You can use an int? as a parameter and it works great. That's not my question or problem. My problem is when you use an object as a parameter and **that** object is using nullable properties, then it breaks. That is what is so strange.